# allow only integers to be input as an argument in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I need a Ruby script that accepts only integers in Ruby 2.1 and above (ie handle Bignum,Fixnum, and Integer).

I have:

```
  def push(val)
    return "only integers can be used" if !val.is_a?(Fixnum) || !val.is_a?(Integer)
```

but if I add Bignum, it doesn't seem to work. What would be the best way to do this? Or a different strategy?

Comment: how about `return "error" unless val.to_i > 0`

Comment: @JakeHeidt So you're saying that neither `0` nor `-6` are integers while `'11'` is?

Comment: if it looks like a duck and it quacks like a duck....

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your logic is a bit backwards. You want to say:

> return an error if `val` is not a `Fixnum` and not an `Integer`

That would be expressed as:

```
if !val.is_a?(Fixnum) && !val.is_a?(Integer)
```

If you add `Bignum` to that pattern then it'll work.

Secondly, `Fixnum` and `Bignum` have been deprecated in favor of just `Integer` as of (AFAIK) Ruby 2.4. Conveniently enough, both `Fixnum < Integer` and `Bignum < Integer` are true in Ruby 2.1 through 2.3 so there's no point to checking `is_a? Fixnum`, `is_a? Integer`, and `is_a? Bignum`, you could just check `is_a? Integer` since:

1. As of Ruby 2.4, `10` and `10**100` are both `Integer`s and `Fixnum` and `Bignum` are on the way out.
2. In Ruby 2.1 to 2.3, both `Fixnum` (e.g. `11`) and `Bignum` (e.g. `11*111`) subclass `Integer` so `11.is_a? Integer` and `(11*111).is_a? Integer` are true.
3. `Fixnum` and `Bignum` went away completely in 2.4, now there is only `Integer`.

Simplify to:

```
return "only integers can be used" if !val.is_a?(Integer)
```

or perhaps:

```
return 'only integers can be used' unless val.is_a?(Integer)
```

or if you want to be a little looser and allow `'23'`, use [`Kernel#Integer`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer):

```
def push(val)
  val = Integer(val)
  #...
rescue ArgumentError, TypeError
  return 'only integers can be used'
end
```

or, depending on how much code you want the `rescue` to apply to:

```
def push(val)
  begin
    val = Integer(val)
  rescue ArgumentError, TypeError
    return 'only integers can be used'
  end
  #...
end
```

or perhaps:

```
def push(val)
  val = Integer(val) rescue nil
  return 'only integers can be used' if(val.nil?)
  #...
end
```